# Android MedialPlayer, where to release and create?

Tags: android

I am trying to play a sound when button is pressed. To do so, I tried few methods :

1 : Created a MediaPlayer under and played it when button is pressed like this :

```
MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.bell);
    mp.setLooping(false);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.seekTo(0);
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}
```

This method worked like charm. But then I wanted to conserve memory and wanted to release MediaPlayer when activity is in background. So I added this

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mp.release();
    super.onPause();
}
```

But now, when activity comes back in foreground it throws an error ( because MediaPlayer is created under OnCreate).
So, I thought to create it under onResume since it is always called.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.bell);
    mp.setLooping(false);
    super.onResume();
}
```

It worked.

Full code is like this :

```
package com.example.learn;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mp.release();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.bell);
        mp.setLooping(false);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1: {
            mp.seekTo(0);
            mp.start();
        }
        }

    }

}
```

just thinking have I done it right? Are there better and easier ways?

Comment: this is right and you don't need `mp.seekTo(0);` it will always play from starting, although if you press button twice then two asynchronous sounds will play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking on your code I think you have done it in a right way. You can Create that in onResume as it is always called. On Create is Called for the first time only.
And Yes ALWAYS call

```
mediaPlayer.relaese();
```

instead of

```
mediaPlayer.stop();
```

Everything in your code is looking right. For more accuracy you can have a glance on this
**[LINK](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/)**